# Calling a C function from a R package with a C++ function of another

Tags: c++, c, r, rcpp, r-package

Hello I have developed a package using `Rcpp` and I would like to use within this package some C code from another package (for reference the package in question is [rkdb](https://github.com/KxSystems/rkdb) and the function is [from_any_k_object](https://github.com/KxSystems/rkdb/blob/master/src/common.c#L133))

I would like to know if this is possible (I think it is as I've seen quite a few question concerning using C code in C++ - not from a package though)

If it is I would be glad to get some examples.

EDIT: I can add 2 minimal packages (using C/C++ resp.) with a unique function for minimal example

Comment: It is doable, but a wee bit involved.  Among my packages, see RcppXts for how to get C code from xts (and see xts about what it does, also from zoo), and/or RApiDatetime and RApiSerialize for exporting.  I think we have some answers here and in other places.  Good luck.

Comment: See https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Linking-to-native-routines-in-other-packages for the official documentation. The authors of `rkdb` have to adjust their package to make that possible!